# The differential of the Gauss normal map from a Lie algebraic view point

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, surfaces

Let  $S\subset \mathbb{R}^3$  be  a  smooth surface  with the Gauss normal map $N:S\to  S^2$.

Then for  every $x\in S$, the  differential $(dN)_x:T_xS\to T_{N(x)}S^2$ can be  considered as  an  endomorphism of the  tangent space $T_xS$ since $T_xS$ is  parallel to  $T_{N(x)}S^2$. So  from  now  on, without any  ambiguity and in a  unique way,   we  count $dN$ as an  endomorphism of  the  tangent  bundle $TS$ of  the  surface $S$. So  $dN$  defines  a  linear  operator  $$dN:\chi^{\infty}(S)\to \chi^{\infty}(S)$$  where $\chi^{\infty}(S)$ is the  space  of  all smooth vector  fields on $S$.

> Under which geometric conditions on $S$ this operator preserve the  Lie  bracket  of  $\chi^{\infty}(S)$? Under which  conditions on $S$, the  range $dN(\chi^{\infty}(S))$ of this operator is  a  Lie  algebra?

Of course we  can ask the  same  question for every codimension $1$ submanifold $S$ of  $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $dN$ is known as the shape operator and is a $(1,1)$-tensor, i.e. an endomorphism of $T_*S$. Based on a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation, I believe that $dN$ has to be either the identity map or the zero map. In the first case, it is a sphere. In the second, it is a flat surface.

Comment: @DeaneYang I think the  eigenvalues of $dN$ are principal curvatures, then for  cylinder it is  neither identically zero  nor "identity". Right?

Comment: that is correct. The eigenvalues of the shape operator are the principal curvatures. And the shape operator of the cylinder is neither the identity map nor zero.

Comment: @DeaneYang  so  my  question can be  read, when  the  shape operator generate a  lie  algebra  morphism on the  space of  vector  fields  on our  surface?When its  range  is  a  Lie  algebra?

Comment: @DeaneYang  Dear  prof. Yang   I  am  sorry if my question is elementary. To  be  honnest I  did not understand a relation between my question and  the part of your  statement that "......this  familly  consist of  either whole  morphisms  or 0 or  identity.."  I  would  appreciate  if  you  more  explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ADDED: I checked my calculation of the first displayed equation, and it appears to be correct. If so, it looks to me that it already implies that $A$ is either the identity or zero and therefore the second paragraph isn't even needed.

The shape operator is an example of a bundle map $A: S\rightarrow S$, where $S$ is a $d$-dimensional smooth manifold. If it preserves the Lie algebra structure of vector fields, then $[AX,AY] = A[X,Y]$ for any smooth vector fields $X$ and $Y$. For any $p \in S$ choose local coordinates $x = (x^1, \dots, x^d)$ such that $p$ is at the origin. For any $1 \le i,j,k \le d$, let $X = \partial_i$ and $Y= x^j\partial_k$. A straightforward calculation shows that at the origin,
$$ [AX,AY] =A^i_jA_k^p\partial_p\text{ and }A[X,Y] = \delta_i^jA_k^p\partial_p. $$
Therefore, at each point in $S$, $A^2 = A$ and therefore $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.

Now suppose $A$ is neither the identity nor $0$ at a point $p \in S$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth vector fields that are nonzero at $p$ and satisfy $AX = 0$ and $AY = Y$ at $p$. Then $A[X,Y] = [AX,AY] = 0$ at $p$. Let $f$ be a smooth function such that $Xf(p) \ne 0$. Then on one hand,
$$ [AX,A(fY)] = 0. $$
On the other hand, at $p$,
$$
[AX,A(fY)] = A[X,fY] = A((Xf)Y + f[X,Y]) = (Xf)AY + fA[X,Y] = (Xf)Y \ne 0.
$$
This is a contradiction and therefore $A$ is either the identity or $0$.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much for your  very  interesting answer  and  your  attention to my question.